# Laravel - parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: laravel

Estou me deparando com um erro ao tentar cadastrar dados no banco.

> ```
> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
> parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
> ```

ProdutoController.php

```
public function cadastrar(Request $request)
{
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
    $result = $request::create($dados);
}
```

produto-formulario.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('cadastrar')}}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <input type="text" name="produto">
    <input type="text" name="descricao">
    <input type="text" name="modelo">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">

</form>
```

Eu sempre fiz dessa forma, utilizando o create. Nunca tive problemas.
Está me apontando algo em `$components = parse_url($uri);` no arquivo Request.php 363

Comment: Mas não se cadastra no banco usando a variável `$request`...

Comment: Desculpe meu amigo. Erro meu.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não estava passando pela model. Agora deu certo.

Produto.php

```
class Produto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['produto', 'descricao', 'modelo'];
}
```

ProdutoController.php

```
public function __construct(Produto $produto)
{
    $this->produto = $produto;
}

public function cadastrar(Request $request)
{
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
    $conf = $this->produto->create($dados);
}
```

Comment: Ah sim, agora `$this->produto->create` faz algum sentido (ao invés de `$request::create`) :)

Comment: Sim, meu amigo! Sou novo no Laravel, estou me familiarizando com ele e essa questão de MVC. Vou dar uma lida na documentação. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Existem varias formas de salvar no banco. Umas delas pode ser assim também.

```
 use App\namespace\Produto;
 public function cadastrar(Request $request)
 {
   $dados = new Produto;
   $dados->produto = $request-> produto;
   $dados->descricao = $request-> descricao;
   $datos->modelo = $request-> modelo;
   $dados->save();
 }
```

Comment: Vou dar uma lida na documentação para saber a diferença do create e do save. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Independente da diferença dessa forma não grava no banco não?

Comment: Grava sim. Já tinha visto o save em alguns tutoriais, mas não lembrava. Vou utilizá-lo.

Comment: Quando vc usa um formulário com poucos dados pode utilizar o save. Mais quando se usa um formulário com muito dados no lado do usuário é bom usar o create por causa de ataques csrf. E o input que contem o token, não se preocupa que ele não vai para o banco de dados. Ele serve somente para esquema de autenticação para barrar o ataque csrf.

Comment: Ah, entendi!!! O formulário que postei acima só tinha 3 input, porém ele terá muito mais. Já sei então qual devo utilizar. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você tem certeza que sabe qual o uso destes métodos?

O `Request::create` é um método pra requisitar uma URL como se *"fosse um navegador chamando"*, um exemplo de chamada via POST:

```
$request = Request::create('minha/rota/existente', 'POST', [
             'foo' => 'bar'
           ]);

$response = Route::dispatch($request);

var_dump($response);//Pega o resultado da reposta
```

Já o `$request->except()` retorna um grupo de valores dos inputs, exceto um especifico, o uso correto seria:

```
$request->except(['_token']);
```

Isto vai rertonar um `array`

Ou seja é uma chamada a parte e não tem sentido passar um `array` (que é o retorno do except) como se fosse um *string* da rota, conforme a documentação https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input

Fora que nenhum desses métodos tem relação como banco de dados ou models do Laravel, eles só fazem é pegar os valores dos INPUTs e o `create` só faz criar uma nova requisição.